# How to view the execution log that GDB stores for record/replay?

Tags: debugging, gdb, reverse, execution

I am interested in seeing exactly what GDB stores to enable reverse debugging. I know that this can be recorded and saved to a file using 'record save filename'.

But I can't open that file (program crash data file type).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That file is an **ELF** file. **ELF** is a specific [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

You can use "gdb exec" and "record restore filename" to restore the status of your program. Then use "rs" to see all the instructions.

Comment: For ELF file format, there are several useful tools, e.g., objdump, readelf to help you see its content.